# Potential Joomla component incompatibility with EventGallery

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.4

Forgive the lack of direction with this question, however I had a my Joomla 3.4 site running fine, then switched to a new host. All of the site transfer went to plan, however one component, Event Gallery by Sven Bluge, which shows a page of photos stopped working.

The page with the component loads all the framework to host the images, but replaces each image with a `blank.gif`

```
<img class="eventgallery-lazyme " data-width="800" data-height="533" longdesc="http://raymondthefox.com/components/com_eventgallery/helpers/image.php?option=com_eventgallery&amp;mode=uncrop&amp;width=50&amp;view=resizeimage&amp;folder=raymondsnapshots&amp;file=IMG_0212.JPG" src="http://raymondthefox.com/media/com_eventgallery/frontend/images/blank.gif" style=" width: 50px; height: 50px; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" alt="Snapshots">
```

Having looked up this issue on the Event Gallery support pages they suggested it could be a `mod_secure` problem, or various PHP permission issues.

I contacted my hosting support with this, they investigated and offered the following information.

```
Declaration of EventgalleryControllerEvent::postSaveHook() should be compatible
with JControllerForm::postSaveHook(JModelLegacy $model, $validData = Array) in
/home/raymygmo/public_html/administrator/components/com_eventgallery/controllers/event.php
on line 16 So we suspect some incompatibilities between Joomla components.
```

Is there any substance in their response, and if so could anyone outline what it means.

Please comment if more/less information is required and I will update the question accordingly. Apologies for running in blind with this one.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is already solved. The answer of your hosting provider is worth nothing. But mentioning the switch to a new hosting provider is a good hint.

Event Gallery uses the script /components/com_eventgallery/helpers/image.php to deliver cached thumbnails. If this script has no execution permission you'll see no images. You can either switch on the slow legacy render mode in the components options or you fix those permissions.